# Turning a Python dict with mutiple values in to a list with every key value pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with changing number of values per key, e.g.

```
my_dict = {'a':['e','f'],'b':['g'],'c':[]}
```

I would like to extract every key value pair in a list, i.e.

```
[('a','e'),('a','f'),('b','g')]
```

So 'c' should not be a part of the list since it has no value associated.

Comment: `c` does have a value associated, an empty list.

Comment: Use a list comprehension `[(k, e) for k, v in my_dict.items() for e in v]`

Comment: oops. I market it duplicate of a wrong question (a unzip) but this question is about dict.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Please post your comment as an answer so it can be properly evaluated. Comments are for clarifications.

Comment: sorry Patrick, please post an answer and i'll delete mine, I didn't see your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# your original data
my_dict = {'a':['e','f'],'b':['g'],'c':[]}

# your list of tuples.
new_list = []
for k, v in my_dict.iteritems(): # .items() in python 3x
    for item in v:
        # For each element in the list, append a tuple (key, current list item) to your output.
        new_list.append((k, item))
```

Outputs:

```
# [('a', 'e'), ('a', 'f'), ('b', 'g')]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with a list comprehension:

```
my_dict = {'a':['e','f'],'b':['g'],'c':[]}

res = [(k, w) for k, v in my_dict.items() for w in v]

# [('a', 'e'), ('a', 'f'), ('b', 'g')]
```

For academic purposes here is a slightly different algorithm:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

my_dict = {'a':['e','f'],'b':['g'],'c':[]}

res = [(i, j) for k, v in my_dict.items()
       for i, j in zip_longest(k, v, fillvalue=k) if v]

# [('a', 'e'), ('a', 'f'), ('b', 'g')]
```